# Emulate/virtualize embedded i586 Linux gateway

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, embedded-linux, yocto, intel-galileo

I'm using a custom distribution created using [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/). It runs on an `Intel Galileo Gen 2` board. The Galileo uses an `Intel Quark X1000` CPU, a 400 MHz processor with an i586 architecture.

To speed up development, I was wondering whether it's possible to virtualize such a board on a modern desktop machine. I haven't been able to find much information about this online, so maybe I'm searching in the wrong direction.

- Are there any existing solutions to emulate embedded gateways?
- How would one approach this, where should I start?
- Would it take a ton of work to get something like this working, or is it a rather generic process?

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Generally, we use Qemu machine to test Yocto images, see [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#qemu-dev-overview). Do you need to test this specific board ?

Comment: @Nayfe This specific board is not strictly required, but to use Qemu, would that mean I have to compile a different Yocto image? Ideally, I would expect to be able to use the same image for the actual board as for the virtual machine. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: It depends on qemu support, but it could work directly with your image. For example,  I use [meta-intel intel-corei7-64 arch](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/conf/machine/intel-corei7-64.conf) and qemu works with it, by including some stuff [qemu-intel.inc](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/conf/machine/include/qemu-intel.inc).

Comment: @Nayfe Thanks a lot for the useful links! I’ll see where I can get using this information.

Comment: (It's i486 to be precise with few additional commands form i586).